# Not able to set height to custom made tab layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I want to create custom tab layout for my application. The problem is I am not able to set height for the same.

Please help to sort out the issue.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/tab_height"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selection_states"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside the TabLayout change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="100dp"` or how many dps you want.

Comment: Got it! Actually I tried this earlier, but something went wrong. So I couldnt see the expected result. So, I posted the question. Now solved.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for your TabLayout. Just use `android:layoutHeight="@dimen/tab_height"`. The same goes for your FrameLayout.